# Multi route, multi template with Sails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sails.js, sails-mongo

I've been wondering if it would be feasible to create an app similar in functionality to Squarespace where once logged in, a user can create a 'micro-site' choosing hers/his own theme for it. The application would then link the user with a db, domain (or subdomain) and a set of routes.

I've considered the following:

1) Have a base app that would be replicated (new instance) every time a new 'micro-site' is created

2) Have one larger app that would route each 'micro-site' to its own db and theme based on user and url structure.

I believe option 1 is cumbersome as it'll generate an awful lot of duplication and would probably become a maintenance nightmare, so naturally option 2 sounds more plausible. The questions now are:

Is there a third option? 
Has anyone done something similar (option in 2) with Sails/Node app? after some research I've seen something similar in [Rails](https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine).
Would at all be feasible and/or good idea doing it in Sails/Node?

Thanks in advance